# select distinct years and their months in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select distinct years and distinct months of those years in a single query from a time stamp column as below

I tried `select distinct year(sc_ts) as years from posts where user_id = 1 order by years asc` I somehow cannot fit the month part in there. Or will this need two different statements and php processing.

I intend outputting it as

```
2009 - Mar, Apr, May
2010 - Apr, Jun, Jul
```

etc

```
"2009-03-22 16:07:48"
"2009-04-22 16:07:48"
"2009-05-22 16:07:48"
"2010-04-22 16:07:48"
"2010-06-22 16:07:48"
"2010-07-22 16:07:48"
"2011-01-22 16:07:48"
"2011-02-22 16:07:48"
"2011-05-22 16:07:48"
"2011-06-22 16:07:48"
"2011-08-22 16:07:48"
"2012-01-22 16:07:48"
"2012-02-22 16:07:48"
"2012-03-22 16:07:48"
"2012-04-22 16:07:48"
"2012-08-22 16:07:48"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.`Year`, GROUP_CONCAT(x.`Month`) AS Months
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(sc_ts) AS `Year`, MONTHNAME(sc_ts) AS `Month`
        FROM
            `posts`
        WHERE
            user_id = 1
        ORDER BY
            MONTH(sc_ts)
    ) x
GROUP BY
    x.`Year`
ORDER BY
    x.`Year`
```

Comment: Jesus... what a query :) I never even knew something like this (sub-queries) was possible. I'll have to look into this this evening. BTW this does the job 100%. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
select distinct year(sc_ts) as years, group_concat(monthname(sc_ts)) as months from posts where user_id = 1 order by years asc
```

Edit: I used `month()` originally, which gave the month number, using `monthname()` returns the name of the month instead.

Comment: This is near, but thing is it'll give you one year and all the months of all the years 2009, March,April,May,April,June,July,January,February,May,June,August,January,February,March,April,August

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT distinct SUBSTRING(year(sc_ts), 6)`